# Advanced HTTP server configurations in Play 2.3

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.1, playframework-2.3

I am using Play 2.3 to develop an application.

I need to set http.netty.log.wire to true which is by default false as specified in Play documents.

In the below link (last section) it says this option is available but it also specifies "we cannot use application.conf" to specify this.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionConfiguration

If we cannot specify this in application conf, how can we specify this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass those options in the command line:

```
/path/to/your/app/bin/yourapp -Dhttp.netty.log.wire=true
```