# Play 2.5 netty access logs

Tags: playframework, netty, playframework-2.5

I am upgrading a play application to play 2.5.3. Need access logs through netty. Configuration we already have ad per answer [Advanced HTTP server configurations in Play 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30816449/advanced-http-server-configurations-in-play-2-3/37648968#37648968) does not work now. Making the log.wire property to true in the application.conf file (as mentioned in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ProductionConfiguration) is not working as well. Is there any other way to enable access logs in 2.5.3 play application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the configuration seems to have changed, it's now  `play.server.netty.log.wire`

Answer (score 1):

@vdebergue: Yes thats right.
 Also  logger name in the logback.xml has changed.

```
<logger name="io.netty.handler" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="ACCESS_FILE"/>
 </logger>
```

The answer for this issue is in https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/6218